# how to write an equation with a special arrow and super and sub scripts

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrows, subscripts, superscripts

How do I generate something like this?I don't know how to generate such arrows and how to write above and below the arrow.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible ways, with `mathtools` and with `chemarrow`.

The `chemarrow` spacing is definitely better, but it's necessary to switch again into math mode for the `\alpha` and `\beta` ... texts, unless other ways of providing the characters are used.

Another method: `stackengine` package by Steven B. Segletes.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\begin{document}

\section{First}


\begin{equation}
  :C \underset{\beta(V)}{\xrightleftharpoons{\alpha(V)}} O 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
:C\; \autorightleftharpoons{$\alpha(V)$}{$\beta(V)$}\quad O
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
:C \autorightleftharpoons{\scriptsize$\alpha(V)$}{\scriptsize$\beta(V)$} O
\end{equation}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

christian hupfer's answer is good, but there's an even more compact version
of his second example, that takes advantage of the optional argument to the
`\x...harpoons` construction to insert the "lower limit".

i think the "default" arrows are too short, so i've forced them to be longer
by adding space around the "upper limit".  a `\quad` is too much, so i've
specified an amount of space that's just a little over half that.

also, in my opinion, there isn't enough space between the arrows and what
they connect, so i've added explicit thick spaces there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  :C \; {\xrightleftharpoons[\beta(V)]{\alpha(V)}} \; O 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  :C \; {\xrightleftharpoons[\beta(V)]{\mkern10mu\alpha(V)\mkern10mu}} \; O 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]